# How to use one default membership provider for two areas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider

I'm building a webshop in MVC 3. It uses the default membership provider for the checkout so users should first register/login before they can make the purchase. This works fine. Now i'm building an admin area to manage all the products, categories and all dropdown values used on the forms. For this the admin needs to log in. Preferably i want to use the same membership provider. What is best practice for this? I tried to put a separate AccountController and views in the Admin area but when i browse to .../admin it will route me to the log on page of the web shop instead of the Admin area. Is it ok to use only 1 AccountController in the root of the project and then evaluate the RouteData and return the correct Logon view from the Admin area Views? or is this 'not-done'.

I would like to do it the best and cleanest way.

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use two account controllers, after all they would have same logic.

You can use Role provider and set access to areas based on roles.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
}
```

**Edit:**

In order to use different layouts, inside a `_ViewStart.cshtml` of your Admin area or inside a view that Admin area `AccountController` is using, you need to set which layout you'll be using:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
```

As for redirects, check your routing inside `AdminAreaRegistration.cs` and also be sure that you're redirecting to area controller:

```
return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Admin", new { area = "Admin" });
```

Comment: I'm already using the 'Authorize' attribute. The problem is that the logon in the checkout and the one in the admin area have different Redirects or RedirectToAction. Also the logon has to use a different layout for both logons. I hope it is a little clear.

Comment: Actually the real problem occurs even before the redirect after logon. When i enter the url 'http://..../admin', it transfers to the logon action of my root AccountController, instead of the one in Admin\Controllers\AccountController.cs. 
When i remove the [Authorize] attribute, the routing in my Amin area  transfers me to Admin\Home\index so the routing is correctly setup in the Admin area. How can i tell my project that Admin will need the AccountController in Admin\Controllers. The layout issue, i can solve with the info in your previous answer. thx for that.

Comment: that is because you are not logged in so it redirects to login page specified in web.config. as far as i know you can specify only one loginurl which will be used to redirect user to login page if he's not already logged in. i see two ways you can work around this: implement custom authorize attribute that will do a proper redirection or implement an attribute that will update layout in based on role (this means one account controller and one view but two layouts).